# Necessary condition for an improper integral of two variables to converge

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm being very confused with an improper integral of two variables.

When an improper integral converges,
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^t f(s)ds 
$$
, it implies $\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} f(s) = 0$.

But, what if the integrand $f(s)$ is changed to $f(t,s)$? 
In other words,

When $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^t f(t,s) ds $ converges,  what can we say about necessary condition  for $f(t,s)$?

- My intuitive answer is 
  $$
  \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \lim_{s\rightarrow t} f(t,s) = 0.
  $$
- For example, if the folowing improper integral converges,
  $$
  \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^t g(s)(1 + t-s) ds 
  $$
  , can we say
  $$
  \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{s\rightarrow t} g(s)(1+t-s) = \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} g(t) =0?
  $$

My guess is true? if so, how to prove it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is not true, that if the improper integral $\int_0^{\infty} f(s)ds$ converges  , it implies that $\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} f(s) = 0$ !!

Take for example $f(s)= \cos(s^2)$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral

Comment: Thank you for your reply! to ensure my claim, the assumption that $\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} f(s)$ exists  is needed.